# How to set jsp file logger level in log4j2.xml

Tags: slf4j, log4j2

I am using Tomcat, slf4j, log4j2.xml as config file. For jsp, how do I set the logger level?

```
<Logger name="what to put here for jsp?" level="DEUBUG">
</Logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

in jsp:

```
<%!
    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("/your/jspfile.jsp");
%>
```

then

```
<Logger name="/your/jspfile.jsp" level="DEUBUG">
</Logger>
```